# Как обрезать строку до N символов с многоточием в конце?

Tags: алгоритм, регулярные-выражения

1. Многоточие не должно разрывать слово.
2. Многоточие не должно продолжать последовательность знаков препинания (даже через пробел(ы). Например, так: `,…` `!!!…` `!!…` `!…` `- …` - получаться не должно.
3. Должны корректно обрабатываться специальные символы unicode типа символа ударения.

Язык программирования любой. Или готовый инструмент.

Условие из пункта 3 - не обязательное.

Почему регулярные выражения. Регулярное выражение преобразуется в автомат, а альтернативные решения "логикой" на скриптовых языках зачастую приводят к временным массивам и т.п. С другой стороны, сейчас много где в скриптах используется JIT, то есть, может подойти и решение циклом.

**Пример.** Пусть дано N = 40 и следующая строка

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!! Consectetur?! Adipiscing elit... Nam tincidunt ultricies congue (turpis duis).
```

Тогда в качестве результата нужно

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
```

Comment: А вам обязательно с помощью регэкспов надо? Просто у меня есть подозрение, что ими вообще нельзя сделать. Если я прав и вас просто интересует алгоритм, то смените метку на `алгоритм` наверно.

Comment: *Язык любой.* - Тогда это невозможно. В каждом свои нюансы. Кстати, а в чём тут проблема? Задача изложена, а где код, выражение, то, что не работает?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew наверно все же речь идет об языке программирования (я надеюсь конечно).

Comment: @Flowneee, дополнил вопрос, почему лучше бы `re`. Любой язык программирования, разумеется.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, [вопросы, где подразумевается работа за автора допустимы и приветствуются](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/Допустимы-ли-вопросы-где-подразумевается-работа-за-автора/4883).

Comment: Да всегда пожалуйста, только вопрос непонятен. Вы бы хоть пример привели: такой-то текст на входе, такой на выходе.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, такой пример подойдёт?

Comment: А почему ожидаемый результат не `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!! Consectetur`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а где тогда у вас там многоточие в конце?

Comment: А, то есть в N входит и многоточие…

Comment: @Flowneee, по идее, это не столь важно. Ведь какая разница, будет ли это число больше на три (на один в случае `…`) или нет.

Comment: Ну строго говоря это может быть важно в языках типа C/C++, где изза такого различия строка может банально не влезть в буфер и положить с грохотом программу.

Comment: @Flowneee, я имел ввиду, что это не важно для алгоритма. Допустим у вас есть алгоритм, который обрезает строку до N с учётом многоточия (как внизу в ответе). Тогда чтобы получить из него неучитывающий многоточие, нужно N увеличить на один (т.е. на длину точек). И наоборот.

Comment: По моему лучший и простейший вариант здесь https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1769

Answer (score 3):

Ну например так (Python 3), без регэкспов, многоточие входит в N:

```python
def truncate_string(str, N):
    substr = str[0: N]
    last_alpha = 0
    for i in range(0, N - 1):
        if str[i].isalpha() and not str[i+1].isalpha():
            last_alpha = i
    return substr[0: last_alpha + 1] + "…"
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/H5jKnc)

Естественно никаких проверок типа "а не вернется ли пустая строка", "а не подается ли на вход пустая строка" я не делал, так как вы не описали как должна функция вести в таком случае, но я думаю, что такое вы сами сможете сделать.

**UPDATE**

Я немного исправил логику работы, чтобы обход начинался с конца строки, так поэффективнее:

```python
def truncate_string(str, N):
    substr = str[0: N]
    last_alpha = 0
    for i in range(N - 1, 0, -1):
        if str[i-1].isalpha() and not str[i].isalpha():
            last_alpha = i
            break
    return substr[0: last_alpha] + "…"
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/ZZiw73)

Comment: Вроде все ок, только падает на строках короче N символов (но это детали, конечно)

Comment: @andy.37 Ну я и сказал что не делал проверок, интересовал же алгоритм в целом

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю, что это конечный вариант, постараюсь дополнить позже, но, возможно, натолкнёт на решение этой проблемы. Моя идея заключалась в том, чтобы разбить строку на две подстроки. Во второй подстроке найти первых несколько слов и добавить к ним троеточие.

```php
<?php
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!! Consectetur?! Adipiscing elit... Nam tincidunt ultricies congue (turpis duis).";
$pre = substr($text, 0, 40);
$after = substr($pre, 20, 40);
$pattern = '/^((?:\S+\s+){2}\S+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $after, $matches);
$k = strlen($matches[1])-1;
$str = $matches[1];
while($k > 0 && !ctype_alpha($str[$k])) {
    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
    $k--;
}
echo substr($pre, 0, 20),$str,'...';
```

Решение вполне себе рабочее и может быть использовано, но совершенно не идеально и требует доработки.

**UPDATE**

Нашел баг, как у себя так и в других решениях на этой странице, словосочетание c дефисом типа `test-test` будет всегда обрываться на первом `test`, если функция определяет его как последнее слово, а остальная часть словосочетания стирается. По этому, поигравшись с regex'ом, я нашел более изящный паттерн(`/^(\w+(-|\s?)\w+)/`), который будет находить либо первых два слова в `$after` либо одно словосочетание разделённое дефисом типа `test-test`. Любые знаки указанные после не влияют на результат выполнения.

```php
<?php
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!! Consectetu-r?! Adipiscing elit... Nam tincidunt ultricies congue (turpis duis).";
$pre = substr($text, 0, 40);
$after = substr($pre, 20, 40);
$pattern = '/^(\w+(-|\s?)\w+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $after, $matches);
$k = strlen($matches[1])-1;
$str = $matches[1];
while($k > 0 && !ctype_alpha($str[$k])) {
    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
    $k--;
}
echo substr($pre, 0, 20),$str,'...';
```

Answer (score 2):

С регуляркой (N = 6 не учитывая многоточия)

```python
import re
p = re.compile(r'^.{0,5}\w\b')
for s in ('abc def', 'abcdefg', 'a, b, c, d', 'abcdef ghi'):
    m = p.search(s)
    if m:
        print m.group(0) + '...'
```

Вывод:

```
abc...
a, b...
abcdef...
```

Вопросы: что делать если

а) строка состоит целиком из знаков препинания?

б) первое слово в строке длиннее N символов?

UPDATE регулярки должны быть "жадными". Но это, вроде, почти всегда так.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуй, предложу и я вариант на [java](/questions/tagged/java)

Основная идея алгоритма: продвигаемся от начала исходной строки **s** к концу, беря по одному слову (и знаки препинания перед ним), проверя, что результат не превосходит заданную длину вместе с многоточием, и добавляем это слово, если оно помещается. Для конструирования используется класс **StringBuilder**.

```java
public static String truncateLine(String s, int n, String suf)
{
    if (s.length() <= n)
        return s;
    if (n < suf.length())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(n);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?u)\\P{L}*\\p{L}+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while (m.find()) {
        String w = m.group();
        if (b.length() + w.length() + suf.length() > n)
            break;
        b.append(w);
    }

    return b.toString() + suf;
}

public static String truncateLine(String s, int n)
{
    return truncateLine(s, n, "...");
}
```

Использование

```java
truncateLine("Мама мыла раму", 12);
```

Результат

> Мама мыла...